# cant pass current Date & Time using Viewdata in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in MVC.I try to pass Current Date & Time by using Viewdata.But it does not get my code is here

```
namespace FirstHelloWorldProjct.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /HelloWorld/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["CurrentTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And my View Code here

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        This is Hello World...<br/>
        The Current Date and time is <%= ViewData["CurrentTime"]%>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And output is here
`This is Hello World...
The Current Date and time is <%= ViewData["CurrentTime"]%>`

Comment: Try using `@ViewData["CurrentTime"]`

Comment: @User3250 thank u it is working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think In Asp.net MVC we use Razor syntax as metion below.

you need to use `@ViewData["CurrentTime"]` instead of `<%= ViewData["CurrentTime"]%>`